# Problem with char * in python

Tags: c++, python

I've just wrapped a header (.h) file and created .so to use it as a module in python. The function Encrypt takes char* bb, then fill it using memcpy(). If I want to call this function from a c code I have to do (char* bb = (char*) new char[200]; Encrypt (...,...,..., bb);). How to call it from python? How is the equivalent of (char* bb = (char*) new char[200];) in python?

```
int Encrypt (string key, string iv, string plaintext, char* bb)
{
std::string ciphertext;

CryptoPP::AES::Encryption aesEncryption((byte *)key.c_str(), CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Encryption cbcEncryption( aesEncryption, (byte *)iv.c_str() );

CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter stfEncryptor(cbcEncryption, new CryptoPP::StringSink( ciphertext ) );
stfEncryptor.Put( reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>( plaintext.c_str() ), plaintext.length() );
stfEncryptor.MessageEnd();

memcpy(bb,ciphertext.c_str(), ciphertext.size());
return ciphertext.size();
};
```

Calling Encrypt() from c:

```
char* bbb = (char*) new char [400];
int sizec = Encrypt(key, iv, plaintext, bbb);
```

I used create_string_buffer("", 400) in python but it does not work.

Comment: "If I want to call this function from a c code I have to do `char* bb = (char*) new char[200];`..."  Surely you mean C++, not C.  The cast is wholly unnecessary.

Comment: What is this `char* bbb = (char*) new char [400];`? You don't need to cast. Just `char* bbb = new char [400];` is enough!

Comment: Your task could be much easier using Cython: http://cython.org

Answer (score 2):

IMHO you can not call C functions directly from python, but it is easy to write a python module, see http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html

**EDIT**

ctype module allows you to call plain C functions directly.

Check this URL for an answer: http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#passing-pointers-or-passing-parameters-by-reference

Comment: Alternatively, use the ctypes module to call C-functions in a DLL directly.

Comment: This is clearly not a C function though.  It is a C++ function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need insert '\0' (terminating null character) at the end of "char *bb". Or use strcpy if your data is string and not binary.
Sorry, not your answer, but you can get memory error.